# Need to show confirmation on deselecting an item from multi select chosen

Tags: jquery

I was trying to implement a feature in which I had to show a confirmation message while deselecting an item from multiselect chosen.

```
$('.search-choice-close').on("click", function(evt){            
          var r = confirm("Are you sure?");            
            if (r == true) {
                $("#divId").val(null).trigger("change"); 

            } 
            else {
                $("#divId").val('').trigger("list:updated");
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Confirmation message is showing, but the item is removing from chosen everytime.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What issue are you facing ? Your question needs to be a bit more detailed

Comment: I feel really sorry for that, The confirmation message is not working properly.my need is to show an conformation alert while deleting an entry from multi select chosen and remove only after confrmed

Comment: What do you mean with "item is removing from chosen"?

Comment: It will be better to add a run-able code snippet

Comment: Hi @Adrian Hope you had worked with chosen multiselect plugin. Here if we are clicking the selected items inside multiselect for deselecting, a confirmation message is showing, but whether clicking "yes" or "no" in confirmation message, the item is deselected. I think she needs to show the deselected item if "no" is selected in confirmation message.